# How can remove/replace substring from GridView Column?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I have below GridView:

[image]

I want to remove `0:00:00` from date column, if exists. I change `dataformatstring` but that remove `9:09:15` too.

I use `auto-generate fields` and `DataBind` on `.cs` file.

I tried `Replace`, but does not work:

```
e.Row.Cells[0].Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Replace("0:00:00"," ");
```

How can I do that?

Gridview:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView4" runat="server" BackColor="White" 
    BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" 
    GridLines="Vertical" Width="98%" 
    Height="100%" onrowdatabound="GridView4_RowDataBound" RowStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#DCDCDC" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#000084" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#999999" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EEEEEE" ForeColor="Black" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#008A8C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#0000A9" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#000065" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OleDbConnection Connection6;
            using (Connection6 = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA.1;Data Source=XXXXXX:1521/orcl;Persist Security Info=True;Password=XXXXXXX;User ID=XXXXXX;"))
            {
            string sqlQuery = "select * from db.user";

            using (OleDbDataAdapter cmd = new OleDbDataAdapter(sqlQuery, Connection6))
            {
                Connection6.Open();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                cmd.Fill(dt);
                GridView4.DataSource = dt;
                GridView4.DataBind();

                Connection6.Close();
            }
        }
    }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of _that_ column? You can set it's `DataFormatString` property as `{0:dd.MM.yyyy}` for example.

Comment: Where you are giving this code `e.Row.Cells[0].Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Replace("0:00:00"," ");` i prefer you to use the same in databind if not

Comment: where is the column section in GridView?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use RowDataBound event, then label control using findcontrol

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server"
        onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
  <Columns>    
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date">
      <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="lblDate" Text='<%# Eval("Date") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
 .....
 </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
   {      
    var lbl =  e.Row.FindControl("lblDate") as Label;
    lbl.Text = lbl.Text.Replace("0:00:00", "");     
   }
}
```

If you don't have Template Field and using Bound Field then Use

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    if(e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Contains("0:00:00"))
       e.Row.Cells[0].Text = e.Row.Cells[0].Text.Replace("0:00:00", "");
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't say that, I use `auto-generate fields`.

Comment: @Rahul Singh:- OP only wants to remove 0:00:00, if exists otherwise no action needed, are you thinking bit different?

Comment: @HaveNoDisplayName - Oops my bad. Yeah didn't saw that.

Comment: @RahulSingh:- np, thats OK